# spring-integration-kafka xml fault

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, apache-kafka

It's strange that I the producer works normally ,But
in the first line of my xml file, there is a fault below:

Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems

### View and select "Show Details..."

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka" />

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
    auto-startup="true" order="1" channel="inputToKafka" />
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
    producer-properties="producerProperties">
        <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
            <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="192.168.11.230:9092"
                    key-class-type="java.lang.String" 
                    key-encoder="encoder"
                    value-class-type="java.lang.String" 
                    value-encoder="encoder"
                    partitioner="partitioner"
                       topic="test"/>
        </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>

    <bean id="producerProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">3600000</prop>
                <prop key="message.send.max.retries">5</prop>
                <prop key="serializer.class">kafka.serializer.StringEncoder</prop>
                <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder" />

<bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.DefaultPartitioner"/>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5"
    keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />
</beans>
```

---

the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X20pz.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the error and in which context is it presented to you? Runtime, development, IDE?

Comment: @hotzst I‘ve add the image of errors . I am using the spring boot(1.2.7.RELEASE) ,eclipse Java EE 4.5.1 .